# SassC::SyntaxError in ActiveAdmin::Devise::Sessions#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, activeadmin

I am using arctic_admin gem . Following https://github.com/cprodhomme/arctic_admin
I have added in the gem file

```
 gem 'arctic_admin'
```

in /app/assets/javascripts/active_admin.js file

```
//= require arctic_admin/base
```

in /app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.scss file

```
@import "arctic_admin/base";
```

in active_admin.rb

```
 meta_tags_options = { viewport: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' }
    config.meta_tags = meta_tags_options
    config.meta_tags_for_logged_out_pages = meta_tags_options
```

in local theme is working. but in development environment I get

```
SassC::SyntaxError in ActiveAdmin::Devise::Sessions#new
Showing /usr/local/bundle/gems/activeadmin-2.12.0/app/views/layouts/active_admin_logged_out.html.erb where line #12 raised:

Error: File to import not found or unreadable: arctic_admin/base.
        on line 1:1 of app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.scss
>> @import "arctic_admin/base";
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: "in local theme is working. but in development environment I get" I was always told local is development. Which env it doesn't work in? Did you add arctic_admin gem to a group in your Gemfile by any chance?

Comment: @MikeSzyndel It is working on localhost:3000, but not on the dev server. And yes, the arctic_admin gem is under the `group :development :test` . Should it be moved outside?

Comment: yes, you should move it out of any groups

Comment: Whatever that "development" server is, it probably actually runs either in staging or production environment. you can check `RAILS_ENV` or `Rails.env` to confirm it

Comment: Thank you @MikeSzyndel. I have moved it outside. Now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue occurred because the gem was added under the :development, :test group in the Gemfile. Following the comment under the post, I have moved it outside of these groups. The issue is now resolved.